# How can I add a new object to an existing Entity, PUT the data and have EF add it to my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using EF5, SQL Server 2012 and a Web Front End. On the server I have the following two classes:

```
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

}
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

I retrieved a question to my front-end application, added an emptyAnswer:

```
   var emptyAnswer = { "answerId"; null, "text": "xx", "questionId": formData.questionId};
   formData.answers.push(emptyAnswer);
```

I then did a PUT to the server and noted that when it went to the server answerId was correctly set to null.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PutQuestion(int id, Question question)
    {
        var a = question;
    }
```

The data is received by my ASP.NET WebApi controllers but when I check the newly created answer object that is now part of my question it has an AnswerId of **0**.

Can anyone tell me why it changes from null > 0 ?  The problem is that when I now do an update Entity 
Framework gives me an error as it is expecting the newly created answer to not have it's AnswerId set.

Please note. I am doing my check before the object gets to Entity Framework. I mentioned I'm using that but at this point I don't think it's come into the picture yet as I just check the poco class. There was some mention below about the field being non nullable. However when I create a new object the payload is similar and for example when I create a "content" object I have the field set to null and it stays as null.

Here's the result of my tests so far. I took the front-end out of the loop so everything is a bit more clear:

Works:

```
var a = new Answer{
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "AA",
    Image = "DDD",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
question.Answers.Add(a);
_uow.Questions.Update(question);
_uow.Commit();
```

Does not work: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

```
var a = new Answer{
    AnswerId = 0,
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "AAA",
    Image = "DDD",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
var b = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = 0,
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "BBB",
    Image = "EEE",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
```

Does not work correctly. It does not create new entity values. It just uses 1000 and 1001

```
var a = new Answer{
    AnswerId = 1000,
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "AAA",
    Image = "DDD",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
var b = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = 1001,
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "BBB",
    Image = "EEE",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
```

Does not work: Compiler error. Can't convert null to int

```
var a = new Answer{
    AnswerId = null,
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "AAA",
    Image = "DDD",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
var b = new Answer
{
    AnswerId = null,
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "BBB",
    Image = "EEE",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
```

Doesn't work: ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

```
var a = new Answer{
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "AAA",
    Image = "DDD",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
var b = new Answer
{
    Correct = false,
    Response = false,
    Text = "BBB",
    Image = "EEE",
    QuestionId = question.QuestionId
};
```

Comment: In your database Ids are 1-indexed (i.e. start 1,2,3 vs 0,1,2) so you wouldn't be able to enter an index of zero anyway.

Comment: It depends if the column is configured as an identity or not. If the column is not an identity column then 0 is a perfectly valid value.

Comment: I'm doing my check of the object and noticing it is 0 before it gets to EF and where it's just a poco class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the AnswerId property on Answer is not nullable

```
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Also, EF apparently thinks you will set the appropriate id's. If AnswerId was configured as an identity column (auto incrementing id's), then EF would not complain.

Comment: My data has not yet got to EF.  It comes over as a null, is received by the controller method and I check it before it gets to EF. You mention not nullable. How can I make the field not nullable? Thanks.

Comment: You make the field nullable by adding a '?' after the type:

public int? AnswerId { get; set; }
However, why do you want it to be null? I don't think it's a good idea to make your primary key nullable...

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework and it's an identity column. I think the only way I can insert data and have the database create a value is if it's null. Please advise me if you have any ideas.

Comment: Oh no, you're wrong. If you save a record with id '0' and the column is configured as an identity, entity framework should have no issue saving it and giving it a proper id. Could you paste the full exception on pastebin or something if that doesn't work?

Comment: Actually when I added it and there's a 0 then I don't see an exception. It just not seem to add it at all. I will try and look into this a bit more and then update. thanks

Comment: Did you call "SaveChanges" on your context? Entity Framework does not "flush" your changes unless you call SaveChanges